# Python return value from class with functions

Tags: python, function, class

I would like to  have a class like this:

```
class Test:
    def __new__(cls):
        return 'test'

    def hi(self):
        print('hi')
```

As you can see, I would like to create a class that returns a value on instantiation, but still uses the functions of the class, so like this:

```
cl = Test()
print(cl)
cl.hi()
```

If anyone can help me, that would be great!

Comment: Every class returns a value on instantiation (or throws an exception...). If you want that value to have the functions of the `Test` class, then it must be of type `Test`.

Comment: Do you want to *print* the string `'test'` when you instantiate `Test`? `cl` in your example can be an instance of `Test`, *or* the string `'test'`, not both (though you *could* return a tuple consisting of both, and write `cl, msg = Test()`, though beware: unless `__new__` returns an instance of `Test`, `Test.__init__` will not be called.

Comment: If you are returning 'test' then you are returning a string instead of the object.  You can use the `__repr__` and `__str__` methods to create human readable information while retaining the object itself for processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
class Test:

    def hi(self):
        print('hi')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'test'

cl = Test()
print(cl)
cl.hi()
```

The method `__str__(self)` is setting the behavior for the class when used as a string.

Comment: This doesn't return `'test'` *on instantiation* in any way, shape, or form (though it does seem to address what the OP actually wants, given the example usage of `cl`).

Comment: I agree with you, it just acts like a string :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you’re looking for something like this.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return 'test'

    def hi(self):
        print('hi')
```

Special Method names could be a good read for you.
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: This is basically the same answer as [@mucio's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57778319/1126841) but with an unnecessary override of `__init__` thrown in.

Answer (score 0):

This does not change the MRO or the class type. It still needs some work.

```
class MethodAdder:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._obj = obj

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._obj)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._obj == other

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self._obj != other

    # ... and so on

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        try:
            if hasattr(object.__getattribute__(self, "_obj"), key):
                setattr(object.__getattribute__(self, "_obj"), key, value)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        object.__setattr__(self, key, value)

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        try:
            if hasattr(object.__getattribute__(self, "_obj"), item):
                return getattr(object.__getattribute__(self, "_obj"), item)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        return object.__getattribute__(self, item)

    def hello(self):
        print("hello2")


v = MethodAdder("test")
print(v)
v.hello()
print(v.split("e"))
```

Answer (score -1):

or maybe this...
class TestMe:

```
def __init__(self):
    print('init')

def hi(self):
    print('hi')
```